# Spring DI with Constructor

Tags: java, spring, constructor

I have the following code:

```
@Component
public class MainBean {

    @Autowired
    private MyTask myTask

    @Autowired
    private TaskScheduler taskScheduler


    public void start() {

        String str = "Print something to console";

        //somehow call constructor and pass str argument??
        taskScheduler.execute(myTask);

    }
}

@Component
public class MyTask implements Runnable {

    private String str;

    @Autowired
    public MyTask(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

I want to call MyTask and pass the str argument to the constructor. How can I do this? I cant find any good examples anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, a good solution would be the following:

```
@Component
public class MainBean {

    @Autowired
    private MyTaskFactory myTaskFactory

    @Autowired
    private TaskScheduler taskScheduler


    public void start() {

        String str = "Print something to console";

        taskScheduler.execute(myTaskFactory.getTask(str));

    }
}


public class MyTaskFactory {

   public MyTask getTask(String str) {
       return new MyTask(str);
   }
}

@Configuration
public class MyTaskFactoryConfig {

   @Bean
   public MyTaskFactory myTaskFactory() {
      return new MyTaskFactory();
   }
}
```

Note that MyTask will then be changed to:

```
public class MyTask implements Runnable {

    private String str;

    public MyTask(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a nice solution but what if I would want to inject an @Autowired dependency in MyTask?

Comment: That case is easily dealt with, by injecting the dependency into MyTaskFactoryConfig, then passed to the MyTaskFactory using the factory's constructor, and then passed to MyTask using it's constructor. Is it clear or do you want me to update the answer with some code?

Answer (score 0):

As seen from annotations,  you've configured `MyTask`  to be Spring managed. Also, `str` property is Spring managed, it should be injected by Spring to `MyTask`.

So, whenever you need `MyTask` instance, you don't create it yourself.

You `@Autowire` wherever you need.

```
public class ClassThatNeedsMyTaskInstances{
    @Autowired
    MyTask myTask;
}
```

But beware that by default, `MyTask` will be a singleton, so you may want to change its scope to  `prototype`.

But this may be a good case where you don't let Spring manage `MyTask`s lifecycle. Instead you manage it yourself by creating instances using `new`, or factory

Comment: Making just `MyTask` a prototype won't do any good if `MainBean` is a singleton. Lifecycle mismatches can be handled by lookup methods, but they seem to have fallen out of favor with annotation-driven configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The following examples are for injecting the string from and XML and a Java-based configuration:

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">


    <bean id="MyTaskConstructor" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg type="char[]" value="My value"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    <bean id="myTask" class="com.package.MyTask">
        <constructor-arg ref="MyTaskConstructor"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Java-based**

```
@Configuration
public class MyTaskConfig {

    @Bean
    public String getMyTaskConstructor() {
        return "My value";
    }

    @Bean
    public MyTask myTask() {
         return new MyTask(getMyTaskConstructor());
    }
}
```